# Retention Policy for sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, retention

Is there a way to apply retention policies to sub-sites in SharePoint Online?
Something with PowerShell PnP where we list the sub-site URL and policy target in Excel?

We have looked at site collection policies from our farm admins, but we could have 30+ sub-sites under these site collections.  To have 1 retention policy at the site collection level and force that on all 30+ sub-sites is a bit restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. It's a limitation in Microsoft.

Then same question has been answered here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-privacy-compliance/retention-policy-for-subsites/m-p/95696

Comment: Thank you.  Wondering if way to automate via PnP library information management policy setting so we could delete files 15+ on last modified date.